# Many to Many nothing happens when persisted?

Tags: jpa, many-to-many

Hi I have two classes Professor2.java and Projects2.java. These are my entity classes and they are related with many to many relationship. This is part of my Professor2 class where I declare List of Project2 instances.

```
   @ManyToMany
private List<Projects2> projects = new ArrayList();

public List<Projects2> getProjects() {
    return projects;
}

public void setProjects(List<Projects2> projects) {
    this.projects = projects;
}
```

Here is part of my Project2 class :

```
           @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "projects",cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<Professor2> professor2s;

public List<Professor2> getProfessor2s() {
    return professor2s;
}

public void setProfessor2s(List<Professor2> professor2s) {
    this.professor2s = professor2s;
}
  public void addProfessor(Professor2 prof) 
   {
    if (!getProfessor2s().contains(prof)) 
    {
      getProfessor2s().add(prof);
    }
    if (!prof.getProjects().contains(this)) 
    {
      prof.getProjects().add(this);
    }
}
```

here is the function that persists Projects and their Professors:

```
      public void addProfAndProj(Professor2 p1 ,Projects2 p2)
{

    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    p2.addProfessor(p1);
    try{
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(p2);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } finally{
        em.close();
    }

}
```

The problem is that the third table which is join table(by the way I created first the entity classes and after that from them the database. )doesn't show any data inside. Where do you think could be the problem.

Comment: please add your join table. for bi-directional many2many you must add the elements to both collections, on both sides of the relationship. Consider replacing List by Set (so you don't have to check if the entity is already there before adding) and before performing the persist operation in addProfAndProj, force JPA to retrieve the latest version of the object using em.find()

Comment: yes you are right thanks that helped.

Comment: @Leo `and before performing the persist operation in addProfAndProj, force JPA to retrieve the latest version of the object using em.find() ` .... optimistic locking ????

Comment: pessimistic actually

Comment: tat's what i am saying ... retrieving the latest version just before an update is like "killing" the optimistic lock ... no ?